# Modelling random structure in lmer and nlme:lme

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, inference

Using the `lme4` package, I can model each random factor of the model differently. For instance,  in this case:

```
lm<-lmer(var~cond +(1|blocks) + (1+cond|sub) , data=data)
```

I set random intercept for blocks and random intercept and slope for sub. How can I do the same using `lme`? I mean, how can I model this in a different way for each random factor of the model using `lme` in the `nlme` package?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the nlme package is not structured to handle non-nested random effects. However if you really wish to create a non-nested random effects model, you need to specify a higher level grouping factor of value one for your random effects, and then create a block diagonal variance-covariance of multiple identity matrices for each random effect.

Unfortunately, I've only seen this kind of "hack" formulation with an intercept only random effects and the computation time will be much longer. Furthermore, the random effects from the lme output cannot be interpreted as you would from the lmer output. The lme output does not give you values for the random effect intercepts.

There's a couple of ways to specify the random effects variance-covariance matrices. You can use a groupedData object or unit auxiliary variables. I'm only familiar with the auxiliary variable method which I'll use in this next example.

---

- Auxiliary variables method

Were using a dataset in the nlmeU package. First, you create auxiliary variables with values of 1 for each random effect variable. Then, you specify the random effect as a list of identity matrices created for each random effect.

```
library(nlme)
library(nlmeU)
fcat1 <- within(fcat, one1 <- one2 <- 1L) # This creates the unit auxiliary variables.
lme_model <- lme(scorec ~ 1, 
             random = list(one1 = pdIdent(~target-1), one2 = pdIdent(~id-1)), 
             data = fcat1)
```

Which gives us the results for the fixed effect

```
Fixed effects: scorec ~ 1 
               Value Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 3.903319 0.4255343 4850 9.172748       0
```

Compared to the lmer model

```
library(lme4)
lmer_model <- lmer(scorec ~ 1 + (1|target) + (1|id), data = fcat1)
summary(lmer_model)
```

With

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   3.9033     0.4255   9.173
```

---

To answer your question, the best formulation to my knowledge you can do for your multiple non-nested effects is intercepts only. After creating auxiliary variables in your data set your model formulation would look like

```
lm<-lmer(var~cond, data=data, random=list(one1=pdIdent(~blocks-1), one2=pdIdent(~sub-1))
```

Before using this method though, you need to ask yourself if the random effects in my model are truly non-nested. If they are, why use the nlme package? The main goal of the nlme package is to model nested random effects and their special variance-covariance structure.

---

Sources :

Chapter 19 of Galecki, Burzykowski  "Linear
Mixed-Effects Models Using R: Step-by-Step Approach"

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-September/025067.html
R help mailing list for a similar question. This link has more info on using the groupedData for representing the random effects. I'm not posting the proposed solution since I don't have a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you original model `lmer(var ~ cond + (1 | blocks) + (1 + cond | sub), data = data)` allows a random intercept by `sub`, a random slope of `cond` by `sub`, and a correlation between these two random effects, the equivalence following DuCorey's specification is

```
lme(var ~ cond, data = data, random = list(
  one = pdIdent(~ 0 + factor(blocks)), 
  sub = pdLogChol(~ 1 + cond)))
```

Here `pdLogChol()` or `pdSymm()` allows the variance-covariance of the random effects to be freely estimated, unlike `pdIdent()` that does not allow random effects of variables specified in the formula to be correlated and requires each to have the same variance (i.e., multiple of an identity variance-covariance matrix for the random terms). The generated model has a first level grouping `one` and a second level grouping `sub`, so that in case of modeling correlation of error terms within groups, use specification like `correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ cond | one/sub)`.

See more caveats from my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643713/how-to-specify-different-random-effects-in-nlme-vs-lme4
about using nlme for crossed random effects.